# Pure Cordova: How to enable live reload for debugging?

Tags: cordova

I am using pure cordova (not phonegap and no ionic). In Ionic, the standard template is pre-installed with capacitor which enable live reload on Android emulator. How can I achieve this in pure cordova?

I use default `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    ......
    {
        "name": "Run Android on emulator",
        "type": "cordova",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "target": "Pixel_4_XL_API_29",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "ionicLiveReload": true
    },
    ......
```

The `"ionicLiveReload": true` does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

> One option that can boost productivity when building Ionic apps is
> Live Reload (or live-reload). When active, Live Reload will reload the
> browser or Web View when changes in the app are detected. This is
> particularly useful for developing using hardware devices.

Just inspect your app with Chrome and hit the reload button, or use location.reload(); from the console.

Comment: The live reload does not work. Every time I run the debugger, the previous chrome://inspect tab will get closed. I have to keep opening new tab to debug it, which takes quite a lot of time. How to enable the live reload? I am not using Ionic, I just use pure Cordova.

Comment: There is no live reload with pure Cordova. Just what I answered.